# Oracle JDK 8 Keytool not found in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

I installed Oracle JDK 8, the Keytool is not located in $JAVA/bin folder. Running whereis, I found the path for Keytool /usr/bin/keytool

Is this keytool different than the JDK keytool? If so, where can I locate the keytool?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of running the keytool command in `/usr/bin/keytool`?  And a side note, the Oracle version of the JDK 8 is no longer being maintained.  The OpenJDK 8 is the official release and should be fairly easy to install on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same, in my enviroment (jdk8) :

```
$ls -ld /usr/bin/keytool
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 Oct 21 10:08 keytool -> /etc/alternatives/keytool
```

Where

```
$ls /etc/alternatives/keytool
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 40 Oct 21 10:08 keytool -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_231-amd64/bin/keytool
```